# How do I get rid of the extra blank line at the end of my listing?

Tags: spacing, listings, itemize

I have the problem that I use a `lstlisting` inside an `itemize`. This leads to the problem of an extra line in my source code block which I'm not able to delete. I already tried nearly every parameter which affects spacing but nothing worked. This is my program:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Visual]{C++},
keepspaces=true,
tabsize=2,
xrightmargin=\parindent,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
frame=single,
framesep=1mm,
framerule=0pt,
columns=fullflexible,
backgroundcolor=\color[gray]{0.9}}

\begin{document}
There are two kinds of header files:
\begin{itemize}
  \item content
  \begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-\baselineskip]
  #include <iostream>
  \end{lstlisting}
  \item more content.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which produces me the following output:

[image]

I've already seen posts dealing with this topic like this one: [vertical extra space below lstlisting environment inside a list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64207/vertical-extra-space-below-lstlisting-environment-inside-a-list-environment)
But setting `\parsep` to `0pt` didn't work for me.

I also tried

```
\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-\baselineskip]
#include <iostream>
\end{lstlisting}
```

like suggested in another post but then I have a problem with my frame.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The blank line at the end of your code is caused by the newline character at the very end of your embedded listing, i.e. at the end of the line

```
#include <iostream>
```

Because `\end{lstlisting}` hasn't been detected yet, `listings` prints that newline character *verbatim*. The same phenomenon occurs with the `verbatim` environment; see the "side note" in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164993/indent-content-of-verbatim-lstlisting-environment-relative-to-containing-envir/164999#164999).

That blank line will go away if you remove the newline character in question, by writing

```
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>\end{lstlisting}
```

instead of

```
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>
\end{lstlisting}
```

See section 2 in my code below.

Alternatively, if you load the `lstautogobble` package and activate the `autogobble` key (which is desirable here, to prevent too much indentation in the output), that extra blank line disappears; see section 3 in my code below.

Also, note that no countermeasure is required for standalone listings, i.e. listings residing in external source files and inserted in your document via the `\lstinputlisting` macro. The extra blank line problem only occurs for embedded listings (i.e. listings contained within an `lstlisting` environment). See section 4 in my code below.

Finally, regarding the space *after* the listing, I usually tweak the value of `belowskip` globally; in your case, `-0.5em` seems appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\lstset
{
  language        = [Visual]{C++},
  keepspaces      = true,
  tabsize         = 2,
  xrightmargin    = \parindent,
  basicstyle      = \ttfamily,
  frame           = single,
  framesep        = 1mm,
  framerule       = 0pt,
  columns         = fullflexible,
  belowskip       = -0.5em,
  backgroundcolor = \color[gray]{0.9},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.c}
#include <iostream>
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\section{Your listing}
There are two kinds of header files:
\begin{itemize}
  \item content
  \begin{lstlisting}
  #include <iostream>
  \end{lstlisting}
  \item more content.
\end{itemize}

\section{Your listing without the newline at the end}
There are two kinds of header files:
\begin{itemize}
  \item content
  \begin{lstlisting}
  #include <iostream>\end{lstlisting}
  \item more content.
\end{itemize}

\section{Your listing with \texttt{autogobble}}
There are two kinds of header files:
\begin{itemize}
  \item content
  \begin{lstlisting}[autogobble]
  #include <iostream>
  \end{lstlisting}
  \item more content.
\end{itemize}

\section{Your listing inserted from an external file}
There are two kinds of header files:
\begin{itemize}
  \item content
    \lstinputlisting{sample.c}
  \item more content.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```