# Excessive vertical space after lstlisting

Tags: spacing, listings

I have created a macro `\piece` to structure longer sections into smaller, numbered pieces. (I am using the macro in a set of lecture notes where I try to introduce one concept per piece.) The code, which I have basically stolen from `\@startsection`, has been working fine so far, but now I am experiencing problems with it in connection with the `listings` package. When I start a `\piece` immediately after an `lstlisting`, there is too much vertical space between the listing and the new piece.

Similar issues with vertical space after an `lstlisting` have been discussed before, but I was not able to derive the answer to my question from the answers:

- [avoid empty vert space after lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118730/avoid-empty-vert-space-after-lstlisting)
- [vertical extra space below lstlisting environment inside a list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64207/vertical-extra-space-below-lstlisting-environment-inside-a-list-environment)

How can I make the code for `\piece` more robust so that this problem disappears?

---

Here is a minimal working example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{piece}
\def\thepiece{\arabic{piece}}
\newcommand*{\piece}{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@afterindentfalse
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addvspace\belowdisplayskip
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{piece}%
  \@afterheading
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\thepiece\quad}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\piece Piece 1

\piece Piece 2

\begin{lstlisting}
Listing
\end{lstlisting}

\piece Piece 3

\end{document}
```

---

Output of the minimal example:

[image: Output of the MWE]

Comment: Are you sure that somethinglike `\section` or `\subsection` isn't better suited for this 'splitting'? And please have a look on [Why should the minimal class be avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: You are right that `\piece` and the sectioning commands are similar; that's why I stole the code for `\piece` from there :). A crucial difference is that there is no title. But perhaps there already is a similar command in some package?

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my answer -- it's of no use to you

Comment: But you spotted the `\leavevmode` typo; that was helpful!

Comment: I think your problem is not with your piece command but as you mention you should use the answer of "avoid empty vert space after lstlisting" -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118733/11820 and control the belowskip of the listing. Either with `\begin{lstlising}[belowskip=-0.8 \baselineskip] …` or with `\lstset{belowskip=-0.8 \baselineskip}`